# Best option for data transfer between on-premises servers and AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My organization is evaluating options of Hybrid Data Warehouse using **AWS Redshift** and **S3**. Objective is to process the data **on-premises** and send processed copy to **S3** and then load to **Redshift** for visualization.

As we are in initial stages, there is no file/storage gateway setup yet.

Initially we used **Informatica Cloud** tool to upload data from on-premises server to **AWS S3**, but was taking long time. Data volume is few hundred million records in history and few thousand records in daily incremental.

Now I have created custom UNIX scripts using **AWS CLI** and using **CP** command to transfer files between on-premises server and **AWS S3** in **gzip** compressed format.

This option is working fine.
But would like to understand from experts, if this is the right way of doing it or if there are any other optimized approaches available to achieve this.

Comment: yeah it's fine!

Comment: The answer to this question comes down to (1) how much bandwidth do you have between your site and AWS, (2) how much processing capacity do you have at your site, and (3) how much developer time you want to invest in building and maintaining your process. If what you're doing works for you and satisfies all criteria, there's no reason to change.

Comment: One thing that you should be aware of, however, is that you _do not_ want to use individual insert/update/delete statements with Redshift (because it's inefficient). Instead, use a `copy` to upload the data and then bulk-insert/update/delete.

Comment: Yes, we are using `copy` command to insert data to Redshift and by nature the system do not have updates/deletes for fact table. DIM tables are truncate and load.

Answer (score 0):

If the volume of your data is more than 100 mb then AWS suggest to use Multipart upload for better performance.
You can refer the below to get the benefit of this
[AWS Java SDK to upload large file in S3](http://www.tryyourskill.com/aws/upload-large-file-s3)